# Joining sql statement in store procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

I am trying to join these two statements in my stored procedure. How would I do that so that I get one table, so that I can use the groupBy column.

```
Select 
  TableA.Name,
  TableB.Occupation,
  'Group1' AS [groupBy]
From
 TableA,
 TableB
Where
 TableA.ID = 1

Select 
  TableA.Name,
  TableB.Occupation,
  'Group2' AS [groupBy]
From
 TableA,
 TableB
Where
 TableB.ID = 10
```

My result should look like this

```
Name    Occupation      GroupBy
David   Doctor          Group1
John    Pilot           Group1
Dwayne  Wrestler        Group2
Axel    RockStar        Group2
```

UPDATE

```
Table A

ID Name  Occupation  
1  David Doctor
1  John  Pilot
2  Mike  Clerk


Table B 

ID  Name   Occupation
3   Wayne  Writer
4   Shane  Publisher
```

10  Dwayne Wrestler
   10  Axel   Rockstar

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about the structure of TableA and TableB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can use a `UNION ALL` to get the result:

```
Select 
  TableA.Name,
  TableA.Occupation,
  'Group1' AS [groupBy]
From TableA
Where TableA.ID = 1
union all
Select 
  TableB.Name,
  TableB.Occupation,
  'Group2' AS [groupBy]
From TableB
Where TableB.ID = 10
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92dd6/3).  A `UNION ALL` will return all rows between the two queries. if you think you might have duplicates that you want to remove, then you can use a `UNION`.

Comment: ...what he said. 8^D Beat me to it.